# Error While running for loop for renaming multiple file in shell script

Tags: linux, unix, for-loop, rename, aix

While renaming multiple file in AIX using for loop I am getting error

> ${fn/$eisinno/$efilename}": 0403-011 The specified substitution is not valid for this command.

**Input File:**

```
raj_10576_INE728J01019_arya1.pdf

ram_10576_INE728J01019_arya1.pdf

rhaul_10576_INE728J01019_arya1.pdf

sanjay_10576_INE728J01019_arya1.pdf

dinesh_10576_INE728J01019_arya1.pdf
```

**Desired Output File:**

```
raj_10576_Remote_sag.pdf

ram_10576_Remote_sag.pdf

rhaul_10576_Remote_sag.pdf

sanjay_10576_Remote_sag.pdf

dinesh_10576_Remote_sag.pdf
```

**My script is as follow:**

```
#!/bin/bash

eisinno="INE728J01019_arya1.pdf"

evenno=10576

efilename="remote_sag.pdf"


cd /home/rishabh/$eveno

for file in *_$eveno_*.pdf

do
    mv -i "${file}" "${file/$eveno_$eisinno/$eveno_remote_$efilename}"

done
```

Kindly help me

Comment: `bash` doesn't send messages like this... this messsage came from `ksh`

Comment: Also `evenno` and `eveno` are different. What you should write is `cd /home/rishabh/$evenno` and `for file in *_${evenno}_*.pdf`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use double `n` in the `evenno`s and use braces to make sure where a variable ends:

```
#!/bin/bash
eisinno="INE728J01019_arya1.pdf"
evenno=10576
efilename="remote_sag.pdf"

cd /home/rishabh/${evenno}
for file in *_${evenno}_*.pdf; do
   echo "Debug: ${file} ==> ${file/${evenno}_${eisinno}/${evenno}_remote_${efilename}}"
   # Alternative: 
   echo ${file} | sed "s/${evenno}_${eisinno}/${evenno}_remote_${efilename}/"

   mv -i "${file}" "${file/${evenno}_${eisinno}/${evenno}_remote_${efilename}}"
done
```

Comment: scr_test1.sh[8]: "Debug: ${file} ==> ${file/${evenno}_${eisinno/${evenno}_remote_${efilename}}}": 0403-011 The specified substitution is not valid for this command.

Comment: Sorry, `${eisinno/` should of been `${eisinno}/`. I corrected it and added an alternative.